# Control is not found exception in Coded UI

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I am entering text in text box using codedUI

```
  HtmlEdit txtbox = new HtmlEdit(bw);
            Playback.PlaybackSettings.WaitForReadyTimeout = 120000;
            txtbox.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlEdit.PropertyNames.Id, "userfilter");
            txtbox.WaitForControlExist();
txtbox.Text = name;
```

If i debug this code it works perfectly fine, if i run this code in vs2013 it gives control not found exception.
bw is my `BrowserWindow` i tried to use `WaitForControlExist` and also increased `WaitForReadyTimeout` nothing worked.

Comment: I'm guessing you debug this code in VS2013 as well? Could it be that the control is somewhere on the bottom of the page and needs scrolling?

If you could try debugging without touching the browser window and let us know what happens.

Comment: @ThomasBouman it is at the top of the browser window and i tried debugging without touching browser window it works perfectly fine. Yes i am debugging in VS2013

Comment: In what way are you running the code when it doesn't find the control? Debug should give back the same result as a normal run as long as nothing is being touched.

Comment: Yes @ThomasBouman i understand it, that's why even i am amazed to see this. While debugging i am not changing a single thing.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with the below mentioned code and reply, if it works are not.

```
HtmlEdit txtbox = new HtmlEdit(bw);
txtbox.SearchPropeties.Add(HtmlEdit.PropertyNames.Id, "userfilter");
// use instance property only, if there are multiple windows opened. currently focussed window will be with the first instance
//txtbox.SearchPropeties.Add(HtmlEdit.PropertyNames.Instance, "1");

if (txtbox.WaitForControlExist())
{
     Keyboard.SendKeys(txtbox, name);
}
```